# Как подгрузить контекст чатов бота в tdlib java?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, tdlib

Пишу сервис для Telegram с `tdlib` на java. Авторизуюсь через `botToken`.

Если попытаться отправить сообщение в чат от имени бота сразу после успешной авторизации `Client`, то получаю ошибку

> Chat not found

Для того, чтобы отправить таки сообщение необходимо еще раз отправить сообщение боту от имени пользователя (хотя до этого уже была переписка). Получается, при перезагрузке приложения каждый раз необходимо будет ждать входящее сообщение от пользователя, что неправильно.

При попытке отправить запрос

```java
client.send(new TdApi.GetChats(new TdApi.ChatListMain(), 1000), resultHandler);
```

получаю ответ

```java
Error {
  code = 400
  message = "The method is not available to bots"
}
```

Также пробовал `LoadChats`, итог тот же.

Вопрос в том, как мне при старте приложения сразу подгружать контекст чатов без ожидания входящего сообщения от пользователя?

Знаю, что можно использовать встроенный `sqlite`, но такой возможности нет из-за особенности окружения.